# The Request/Response Cycle

Tags: web-development, architecture, http, http-request, http-response

When User A decides he want to pay a visit to http://example.com/ it all begins with a Request. A short moment later he is given a Response. In this cycle Request-Response a lot is going on, in different frameworks it's decoupled in different components among them Routing, Dispatching, etc.

I'm looking to make a simple experimental MVP Framework for my learning, trying to use as many best practices, heck who knows it might even be worth using when I'm done.

I'm not sure how I should decouple this cycle in to these different components and I'm not even sure of what each component is responsible for (Thinking SOLID, DRY, SRP, etc). That is what I am asking, looking at different frameworks these components seem to have different use-areas from time to time.

What is each of these components responsible for and in what order are the used?

Request, Response, Dispatcher, Router, Front Controller, Bootstrap, Events.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap

The **bootstrap** file is the entry point of your application (`index.php`). It contains code in the global scope (and this is the only place, where that should be the case). In an outline, it does

- create a **request** object from the request
- create a **response** object according to the requested resource type
- ask the **router** for the responsible controller for the current **request**
- create the **controller** and call its main method, providing it with the **request** and **respond** objects (this often is called **dispatching**)
- echo the **response**

### Request

The **request** object is used to abstract from the web environment. In the end, it is just a data container (often a copy of `$_REQUEST`) that allows you make subsequent calls to other controllers (see *HMVC*).

### Response

The **response** object is managing the output. You may have different response classes for XHTML, HTML5, PDF, JSON, ..., you_name_it with an identical interface. It is responsible for messaging warnings and errors to the user, too.

### Router

The **router** knows, which controller is assigned to which kind of URL. Given the **request**, it makes a decision about the **controller** and returns that to the **bootstrap**.

### Dispatcher

A **dispatcher** is used in different situations. You may think of it like a *map and call* thingest. For our case, the **bootstrap** file and the **router** together make up a dispatcher. A **dispatcher** is also used to map **events** to the various event handlers (plugins) and execute them (often using the *Observer* pattern).

### Front Controller

A **dispatcher** mapping URLs to controllers and executing them dependend on the **request** is also called a **front controller**.

### Events

the **event** mechanism is used to decouple systems. You can for example create plugins that take influence on the result of the router. The only thing you have to do for that is to dispatch some events (eg. `onBeforeRoute` or `onAfterRoute`) in the routing method. `onBeforeRoute` would get the **request** and could change it, before the router even looks at it; `onAfterRoute` would be able to change the router's output. This is just a small example of whjat you can do with events.

Comment: What does the Router return to the so far non-initialized Controller?
I'm not sure I follow the difference between the dispatcher/front controller objects.

Comment: Sorry, ment bootstrap instead of controller - going to correct that. -- Thats the point: Bootstrap+Router == Front Controller (which in fact is a special Dispatcher)